# LINQ query for SQL HAVING CLAUSE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

[Re-Written: 31/01]
I have this problem where I am trying to re-produce a SQL query where I used HAVING ... AND.

The table below shows simplified view of Stores table (ID) and Asset (A-F are types or names of assets).
My View posts to controller a list of Names (which comes from checkboxes implemented using MvcCheckBoxList).

[image]

The result of my query should be a list IDs where each ID has at least one of every asset name selected.

Examples
- List of Names includes A and B return ID { 4 } only
- List of Names = A, C and E returns IDs { 4 and 6 }

**SQL query**
Previous I used a loop to create a text string which concatenated subsequent AND clauses together and was passed as a SQL connectionString.

Example 1 above would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Stores S, ....(all other columns required)
LEFT JOIN Assets A ON S.ID == A.SID
WHERE (DATE ....)
HAVING (count(case when A.Name == "A" then 1 else NULL end) > 0) AND (count(case when A.Name == "B" then 1 else NULL end) > 0)
GROUP BY S.ID;
```

It's the HAVING .. AND that I need to reproduce.

**Linq query**
I have tried this

```
stores = (from s in stores 
join a in db.Assets on s.ID equals a.StoreID
where (postedTillNames.Contains(a.Name)).Distinct().ToList();
```

but this returns any Store which has any Name. postedTillNames is the posted back from View in Model and is an array of string.

**Solution using for loops**

So I found a non-Linq workaround which I will use for time being, but would like to use clean linq if possible (and learn something too ;-):

```
List<Store> tillStores = new List<Store>();
foreach (var s in stores)
{
    bool r = true;

    for (int c = 0; c < postedTillNames.Count(); c++)
    {
        r = (s.Assets.Where(a => a.Name == postedTillNames[c]).Count() > 0) ? true : false;
        if (!r) break;
    }

    if (r) tillStores.Add(s);
}
```

Thank again for your posts and comments so far.

Regards
Craig

---

UPDATE: I have re-written the question completely so please read from the top

Comment: I can't really understand what you're trying to do.  Please include the SQL you wrote that does what you want.  Your explanation is a bit confusing.  What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: Hi. Sorry about lack of explanation.
I am trying to replicate a
SELECT * FROM Store S JOIN Asset S ON S.ID = A.StoreID
WHERE A.NAME = "A" AND A.NAME = "B"

Comment: So where does the Having come into it then?  You're still not explaining the whole situation.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote this query a while ago in SQL using 
Select * From Stores S LEFT JOIN Assets A where S.ID = A.S_ID
WHERE ..... HAVING count(case when A.NAME = "A") > 0 AND count(case when A.NAME="B") AND ... etc.
Hope this shows how I was using HAVING,
The same business logic applies to the problem now although I have simplified what is counted.
Cheers

Comment: Add the queries to the question, do not post comments as updates to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following class structure:

```
class Store
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Asset
{
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

and data:

```
List<Store> Stores = new List<Store>()
{
   new Store { ID = 1, Name = "First"},
   new Store { ID = 2, Name = "Second"},
   new Store { ID = 3, Name = "Third"},
   new Store { ID = 4, Name = "Fourth"},
   new Store { ID = 5, Name = "Fifth"},
   new Store { ID = 6, Name = "Sixth"}
};

List<Asset> Assets = new List<Asset>()
{
    new Asset { StoreID = 1, Name = "B"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 1, Name = "B"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 1, Name = "F"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 1, Name = "F"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 2, Name = "A"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 2, Name = "A"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 2, Name = "C"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 2, Name = "D"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 3, Name = "B"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 3, Name = "B"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 3, Name = "B"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "A"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "B"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "C"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "C"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "D"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "D"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "D"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "E"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 4, Name = "F"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 5, Name = "D"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 6, Name = "A"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 6, Name = "A"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 6, Name = "C"},
    new Asset { StoreID = 6, Name = "E"}
  };
```

as a mockup of the real tables and data stored in the DB, you can use the following Linq query to get what you want:

```
string[] postedTillNames = { "A", "C", "E"};

var result = (from s in Stores
             join a in Assets on s.ID equals a.StoreID
             group new { A = a, S = s } by a.StoreID into assetsGroup
             where !postedTillNames.Any(p => !assetsGroup.Select(g => g.A.Name)
                                                         .Contains(p))
             select assetsGroup.First().S).ToList();
```

The above query returns a `List<Store>` object containing stores with ID = 4, 6.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. If you could please explain how the group and where clauses work.that would be even more brilliant! Thanks.